# Dynamically generate inline css styles for email templates in Symfony2

Tags: php, css, symfony, twig

Is there a tool or a bundle in Symfony2 that allows me to create normal templates with css files, and then on the fly convert it to inline css rules so it can be used as the body of an email?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I know of three tools that can do this and which you can use in Symfony:

- [Premailer](http://premailer.dialect.ca/api) is an online tool which provides this service. It has an API and a php wrapper for that API
- [CssToInlineClass](http://classes.verkoyen.eu/css_to_inline_styles) is a php class that offers this functionality
- Mailchimp offers a [function in their api](http://apidocs.mailchimp.com/api/1.3/inlinecss.func.php) that offers this functionality

The first two don´t have a direct symfony implementation, though they will be easy to use. For mailchimp, there is a [mailchimp bundle](https://github.com/jirafe/MailChimpBundle) which offers this functionality, though the bundle is not very well documented.

Comment: Thanks, CssToInlineClass looks like the way to go for me

Comment: Maybe you can create a public bundle for that class and share it with everyone :-)

Comment: haha it will be very nice but first I have to learn how to create a bundle for sharing in github. But I will keep it in mind.

Comment: These is a Symfony 2 bundle to be found here: https://packagist.org/packages/robertotru/to-inline-style-email-bundle as mentioned in one of the answers by @JeanValjean

Answer (score 4):

Today I discovered through another question that exists such a Symfony2 bundle that fits your needs (I didn't tested it).

You can use [ToInlineStyleEmailBundle](https://github.com/robertotru/ToInlineStyleEmailBundle), it embeds the [CSSToInline](http://classes.verkoyen.eu/css_to_inline_styles) library that [Carlos Granados](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1557651/carlos-granados) suggested in his answer.

With this Symfony2 bundle you can get the converter as a service (`$this->get('css_to_inline_email_converter')`) and then use it for your needs. It also supports templates generations.

Answer (score 2):

I've had great results with integrating the Emogrifier PHP class within CakePHP. Inlines all styles very nicely. Not sure if it has a Symfony bundle but shouldn't be hard to integrate.

https://github.com/jjriv/emogrifier